# Is there a classification of symmetric monoidal closed structures on $\mathbf{Ab}$?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-groups, monoidal-categories

How much is known/has been studied about symmetric monoidal closed structures on the category of abelian groups $\mathbf{Ab}$ up to equivalence? Is there any nice characterization of the usual tensor product of abelian groups among these?

Comment: Do you know of a closed symmetric monoidal structure that is not $\otimes$?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer No, but i wasn't be able to prove or find any reference proving or disproving that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is exactly one (symmetric) closed monoidal structure on the category of abelian groups (up to equivalence). This is Proposition 3 of Foltz–Lair–Kelly's [Algebraic categories with few monoidal biclosed structures or none](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404980900821).